# Adding a number id to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

```
SELECT top 5
day_description,
count(numberofdays) as number

FROM mytable

where department = 'departmentname'

group by day_description
```

my select brings something like this back:

```
day description           number           
holiday                     32               
working day                 212              
training day                5                
meeting day                 26               
admin day                   66
```

Is there a way of adding an new column where it asigns either 1-5, 1 being the highest value row, and 5 being the lowest value row. And looks like this:

```
day description           number           top5ID
holiday                     32               3
working day                 212              1
training day                5                5
meeting day                 26               4
admin day                   66               2
```

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: What is your goal? It's know which row is highter?

Comment: I am using this in SSRS BIDS to produce a barchart, I want to be able to specify the colours of each bar depending on their top 5 position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT top 5
        day_description,
        count(numberofdays) as number
    FROM mytable
    where department = 'departmentname'
    group by day_description
)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CTE.number DESC) AS Top5ID,
    CTE.*
FROM
    CTE
```

Or without CTE:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.number DESC) AS Top5ID,
    t.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT top 5
        day_description,
        count(numberofdays) as number
        FROM mytable
        where department = 'departmentname'
        group by day_description
    ) AS t
```

Comment: This works although puts the highest value as 5 rather than 1

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the answer. Please test it again :P

Answer (score 1):

So, you can use it:

```
SELECT TOP 5 day_description, COUNT(numberofdays) AS number, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(numberofdays) DESC) AS Top5ID
FROM mytable
WHERE department = 'departmentname'
GROUP BY day_description
ORDER BY COUNT(numberofdays) DESC
```